# Mybatis: Map part of the SQL to HashMap inside POJO

Tags: java, mysql, mapping, mybatis

In my daily work, I found the necessity of mapping a SQL to its POJO. Besides the columns of the POJO itself, I had some calculated columns that needed to map somewhere. Mapping it to new variables in the POJO didn't seem the best option, as I actually didn't know how many new columns I would need (now and in the future).

Example SQL:

```
select id, name, surname, 
  calculated_column_1, calculated_column_2, ... 
  from person
  left outer join ...
```

`calculated_column_1` and `calculated_column_2` are -- as their name say -- calculated columns depending of another table.

I didn't know if I was going to need 1, 2 or N calculated columns.

How can it be mapped to the pojo?

Comment: appreciated if you answer to your own question. not it the question section

Comment: Change it right away. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After many tries, I found the solution as follows:

POJO:

```
private int id;
private String name;
private String surname;
private HashMap<String, Object> aditionalColumns;

// getters & setters
```

MyBatis Mapper:

```
<resultMap id="BaseResultMap" type="Person" automapping="true">
  <id column="id" property="id"/>
  <association
      property="aditionalColumns"
      resultMap="aditionalColumnsMapper" 
      columnPrefix="calculated_" />
</resultMap>

<resultMap id="aditionalColumnsMapper" type="map" autoMapping="true"/>
```

In this case, my aditionalColumns HashMap would look like this after mapping:

```
{column_1=value1, column_2=value2}
```

Note: I didn't know how many columns I needed, if you know exactly how many you need, and it won't change, you can map only your columns changing the second resultMap as follows:

```
<resultMap id="aditionalColumnsMapper" type="map">
    <result column="calculated_column_1" property="calculated_column_1"/>
    <result column="calculated_column_2" property="calculated_column_2"/>
</resultMap>
```

Comment: This is just what I needed. MyBatis awesome as always.